# How to install latest docker-compose without docker desktop

Tags: ubuntu, docker, docker-compose

I have installed docker this way https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-using-the-repository

```
└─$ docker --version
Docker version 24.0.5, build 24.0.5-0ubuntu1~20.04.1
```

then trying to install docker-compose but it was version 1.24 .
I need >= 1.9 version of docker-compose without "docker desktop" installation, how to do that?

Comment: 1.24 is >= 1.9?

Comment: Version 1.24 is NOT version 1.2.4, and it IS a more recent version than 1.9, because 24 is a large number than 9. Have you checked to see if the system is working? Do you actually have a problem, or are you unsure whether or not you have a problem? Test to make sure you have a problem or not, and then come update this question, if appropriate, with more details.

Comment: As above. 1.9 isn't 1.09. And in any case when using a software repository you can only install the version available in said repo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`docker-compose` is now a plugin of the Docker client so it can be runned as `docker compose` (with a space).  This mean that you already have it installed.  For confirmation you can try

```
docker compose version
```

or even

```
docker compose
```

to get a small help page.

The new compose is almost backward compatible with the old one, the differences are described in the [official documentation](https://docs.docker.com/compose/migrate/#what-are-the-differences-between-compose-v1-and-compose-v2) where the old `docker-compose` is called "Compose V1" and the new one is called "Compose V2".